# Starter is not very sensitive

Tags: unity, mouse, launcher

Unfortunately the starter used in unity, when hidden, is not sensitive enough. Even if I use the highest sensitivity setting it won't show up unless I hit the border of the screen really hard with my mousepointer. It's not very intuitive that it only responds when hitting the border. Is there a way to alter the region of sensitivity?